# Smart Contracts and Web3

Tags: web3js, etherscan, smart-contract

Is it that when I use smart contracts for storing and retrieving data to and from blockchain, the smart contract automatically stores data in the next to be added block as well as runs through the blockchain and fetches data for me?
Because in layman terms if I have to search for a data stored in blockchain I have to literally scan through the blocks and fetch the data that I require but with Smart Contracts looks like it is just a matter of calling a function for data fetch and it automatically scans, finds the relevant information and give back the result to me?

Comment: You do not have to scan every block to find the latest set of smart contract. The current data is saved in every block. Mostly it is the same as the last block so it isn't saved *again* but rather the same data is re-used.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it that when I use smart contracts for storing and retrieving data to and from blockchain, the smart contract automatically stores data in the next to be added block as well as runs through the blockchain and fetches data for me?

For storing data, yes, If your transaction is validated by a validator, the validator will package your transaction into a block and broadcast it in the network.

For reading data, no. You just need to send a contract call to your blockchain node and retrieve the result.

For example in [this contract](https://Is%20it%20that%20when%20I%20use%20smart%20contracts%20for%20storing%20and%20retrieving%20data%20to%20and%20from%20blockchain,%20the%20smart%20contract%20automatically%20stores%20data%20in%20the%20next%20to%20be%20added%20block%20as%20well%20as%20runs%20through%20the%20blockchain%20and%20fetches%20data%20for%20me?) there are two types of calls: read contracts and write contracts.

- read contract - retrieving information - no block generated
- write contract - writing information - block generated

> if I have to search for a data stored .... a matter of calling a function for data fetch and it automatically scans

For historical data, you need to send your call block by block. For example, checking the past owners of an NFT.

If you are only interested in the most recent data you don't need to do this. Every client/node in the network are updated with the latest data so you don't have to do it block by block.